# Can NSShadowAttribute be applied to NSMutableArray or have to convert NSMutableArray to NSMutableString?

Tags: ios

I have a NSMutableArray of text on which i want to apply NSShadowAttribute. Is there a way to accomplish this or have to convert first NSMutableArray to NSMutablestring so that NSShadowAttribute can be applied on it.

```
 self.textArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"This specification does not indicate    the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters. For this reason, authors should use appropriate elements and styles to achieve visual formatting effects that involve white space, rather than space characters".
```

This is the NSShadowAttribute code which i want to apply on NSMutableArray.

```
    UIColor *_green=[UIColor greenColor];
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:72.0f];

    NSShadow *shadowDic=[[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [shadowDic setShadowBlurRadius:5.0];
    [shadowDic setShadowColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [shadowDic setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 3)];

    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
    [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_green range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
    [attString addAttribute:NSShadowAttributeName value:shadowDic range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
```

Pls can someone tells me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert the `NSMutableArray` to anything, but you have to convert its *contents* to `NSMutableAttributedString`s in order to add attributes to them, ex:

```
// Create an array to hold the new attributed strings you're
// about to create (so that you don't change the original array
// directly upon enumeration)
NSMutableArray *textArrayCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Go through your text array
for (NSString* string in self.textArray) {

    // Convert the string at the current index to an
    // NSMutableAttributedString
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

    UIColor *_green=[UIColor greenColor];
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:72.0f];

    NSShadow *shadowDic=[[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [shadowDic setShadowBlurRadius:5.0];
    [shadowDic setShadowColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [shadowDic setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 3)];

    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_green range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    [attString addAttribute:NSShadowAttributeName value:shadowDic range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

    // Add the attributed string to the new array
    [textArrayCopy addObject:attString];
}

// Set the original array to contain the contents of the new array
// you've just created
self.textArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:textArrayCopy];
```